# MySQL Query: find the category id in the products table, however id is wrapped like `&12&`

Tags: php, mysql

I need to find the category id in the products table below. However the `cms_ecom_categories.id` is wrapped with the `&` character like `&12&`.  Is there some kind of wild card I could use to wrap around? like `%cms_ecom_categories.id%` ?

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM cms_ecom_products, cms_ecom_categories 
         WHERE cms_ecom_products.pCategories = cms_ecom_categories.id
               AND cms_ecom_categories.slug = ".$page."";
```

Comment: sorry for the bad formatting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LIKE` => `WHERE id LIKE %12%`

Or add the &-signs to the id: `$page = '&' . $page . '&'` => `WHERE id = $page`

Comment: So the syntax should be something like:

$sql = "SELECT * FROM cms_ecom_products, cms_ecom_categories WHERE cms_ecom_categories.id LIKE %cms_ecom_products.pCategories% AND cms_ecom_categories.slug = ".$page."";

Comment: Sorry, thought it was about the $page variable. Try this: `LIKE CONCAT('%', cms_ecom_products.pCategories, '%')`; that should make it work.

Answer (score 1):

- Either use `AND cms_ecom_categories.slug = '&".$page."&'` - just put the ampersands in the quotes
- Or use the _ wildcard, meaning *exactly one character*: `AND cms_ecom_categories.slug LIKE '_".$page."_'`
- Or use the % wildcard, meaning *zero or more characters*: `AND cms_ecom_categories.slug LIKE '%".$page."%'`

It might be better to modify the $page variable itself though. And why are you building SQL-queries from a string? You should check [parameterized queries](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html) or at least [escape](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), it's easier and more secure.

Comment: Thanks Konerak, my actual full statement consists of (which i believe is secure)
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cms_ecom_products, cms_ecom_categories WHERE cms_ecom_categories.id LIKE %cms_ecom_products.pCategories% AND cms_ecom_categories.slug = ".$page."";
    $stmt = Record::$__CONN__->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->execute();

Comment: It depends if you escape the page variable before or not. You might want to put `AND cms_ecom_categories.slug = ?` and later do `$stmt->execute($page)` :)

Comment: Konerak its actually cms_ecom_products.pCategories that needs to be wrapped in &.  Do you know the syntax for that?